# How to Reload to same Page while sending a parameter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I need to reload the page whenever different buttons are pressed, while sending a String to the same page so that on `created()` it takes that String and sends an HTTP Get into my Database.

Currently I have the following:

```
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            events: [],
            formData:{
                sportType: 'Ténis'
            }
        }
    },

    created(){
        //Do something here to get the value sent from the reloading
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8001/evento`, {headers: {sportType: this.formData.sportType}})
            .then((response)=>{
                this.events = response.events
            },(error) =>{
                console.log(error);
        });
    },
    pickSport(item){
                
    }
```

The function `pickSport()` is called whenever the buttons are pressed and each sends a value to this function that is a String. The idea now is to be able to reload the page when this function is called, while sending this `item` to the reloaded page, so I can update the value of `sportType`. I tried:

```
        pickDesporto(item){
            this.$router.push({
                path: '/betting',
                params: item
            });
        }
```

But with no success, since it keeps giving me a NavigationDuplicated error. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

They are many way to do this. You may want to use Watch: {} to keep track of certain parameter. It will be trigger once the parameter change and you can re-render the same page with new parameter.
There is also a way called key-binding but it need to bind the key to the component. I personally suggest this one because it will be easy to understand.